# Purchase an app for the name

Tags: ios, app-store

The company I work for is busy in developing an enterprise app for both iOS and Android platform. The problem we've run into is that on the iOS app store, the name we need is already taken. So before we start experimenting with other options for the app name, we want to approach the developer and make him an offer for the name/or app, seeing as it seems like an inactive app with very low downloads.

Is this something worth looking at? Is this even a plausible option to explore?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the help center

Comment: @Pierter Hope my answer helped you

Comment: It did, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an option to solve your problem.
You can buy that app by contacting the developer, and then you can change the entire setup.
The developer can transfer the app from his/her account to your company's/your account.